# Renomear coluna com Rails usando migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

criei uma migration para renomear uma coluna e só recebo o erro;

> undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass

```
== 20161001182840 RenameColumnPasswordInUsersPasswordToPasswordDigest: migrating                                  
-- rename_column(:users, :password, :password_digest)                                                             
rake aborted!                                                                                                     
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:                                     

undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass
```

o código da migration é:

```
def change
   rename_column :users, :password, :password_digest
end
```

Comment: Opa, deu certo?
Então, hoje tive uma problema com migration aqui na empresa, precisei ir no banco de dados e apagar manualmente a migration dentro da tabela "schema_migration" e rodar o rake db:migrate novamente, mas nao foi problema com alterar nome não... hehe, só pra compartilhar! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara, quando eu preciso renomear eu faço da seguinte maneira

```html
def self.up
  rename_column :users, :password, :password_digest
end

def self.down
  rename_column :users, :password_digest, :password
end
```

Quando ele da erro com o self. eu uso sem ele...

Igual nosso amigo comentou acima, fazer um **rake db:rollback** pode te ajudar a resolver caso tinha algum problema em alguma migration, porém, se está replicado com o em produção **NÃO FAÇA** e mande pra produção, apenas para teste.

Espero ter ajudado! Abraço!

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente o erro está em alguma migration antiga que você fez, adicionando uma coluna com o nome errado. Tenta executar o comando ***rake db:rollback*** após identificar o erro.

Por exemplo, se você adicionou uma coluna com o tipo :inteer, ou :strig, quando era pra ser :integer ou :string, respectivamente.

Se não conseguir dar o db:roollback apaga a tabela e cria ela novamente.